# OpenCV java One Line needed to Explain about Detection

Tags: java, opencv

sorry for my question i'm going to learn about openCv  in java and one example i found that have line with something i can't understand

```
detections = detections.reshape(1, (int)detections.total() / 7);
```

From full code :

```
public class DeepNeuralNetworkProcessor {

    private Net net;


    private final String[] classNames = {"background",
            "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat",
            "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair",
            "cow", "diningtable", "dog", "horse",
            "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant",
            "sheep", "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"};


    public DeepNeuralNetworkProcessor() {
      this.net = Dnn.readNetFromCaffe(Files_Path.DDN_PROTO, Files_Path.DDN_MODEL);
    }


    public List<DnnObject> getObjectsInFrame(Mat frame, boolean isGrayFrame) {

        int inWidth = 320;
        int inHeight = 240;
        double inScaleFactor = 0.007843;
        double thresholdDnn =  0.2;//Minimum value to detect the object
        double meanVal = 127.5;

        Mat blob = null;
        Mat detections = null;
        List<DnnObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

        int cols = frame.cols();
        int rows = frame.rows();

        try {
            if (isGrayFrame)
                Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

            blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(frame, inScaleFactor,
                    new Size(inWidth, inHeight),
                    new Scalar(meanVal, meanVal, meanVal),
                    false, false);

            net.setInput(blob);
            detections = net.forward();
            detections = detections.reshape(1, (int) detections.total() / 7);


            //all detected objects
            for (int i = 0; i < detections.rows(); ++i) {
                double confidence = detections.get(i, 2)[0];

                if (confidence < thresholdDnn)
                    continue;

                int classId = (int) detections.get(i, 1)[0];

                //...
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return objectList;
    }


}
```

can anyone explain what this line does ?
or better clear explain about the detection mat.
and what net.forward do?
please send me some reference for java opencv or deeplearning4j

Comment: OpenCV dnn need a blob image to handle so you convert your image to blob image and ```net.forward()``` send this blob to network. Your ```reshape```  creates *1xChannel* and *detection.total()/2 x rows* data

Comment: thanks for replay but i can't get it  "Your reshape creates 1xChannel and detection.total()/2 x rows data " meaning can share an example or extend your answer?